# Can anyone tell me step by step way to install Logkeys Keylogger in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

Can anyone tell me step by step way to install Logkeys Keylogger in Ubuntu 14.04? 
I saw the various answer on this forum but none of them is working exactly.I want to know it for educational purpose only.

Comment: see https://github.com/kernc/logkeys/blob/master/INSTALL  The answer is technically a copy paste from their website. Where do you run into problems following those instructions?

Comment: @Rinzwind - Thanks for your timely response.Highly Appreciate.               Empty log file...this is something which has boggle my mind.

Comment: @Rinzwind - Thanks for your timely response.Highly Appreciate.               Empty log file...this is something which has boggle my mind.This is what Ihaddoneafterinstallinglogkeys.                                                                                       exam@mistcslab1pc26:~$ sudo logkeys -k 
[sudo] password for exam: 
exam@mistcslab1pc26:~$ sudo logkeys -s 
exam@mistcslab1pc26:~$ sudo nano /var/log/logkeys.log
Use "fg" to return to nano.

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo nano /var/log/logkeys.log
exam@mistcslab1pc26:~$

Comment: Please edit your question, when you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Please explain what you mean by "empty log" (build or application related).

Answer (score 1):

From the [installation instructions](https://github.com/kernc/logkeys/blob/master/INSTALL)

- Download the [source](https://github.com/kernc/logkeys/archive/master.zip).
- You need to install "autotools" and can do that with ...

  ```
  apt-get update
  apt-get install -y autotools
  ```
- The installation is done with:

  ```
  $ cd ~/Downloads/
  $ unzip logkeys-master.zip    
  $ cd logkeys-master

  $ ./autogen.sh    
  $ cd build       
  $ ../configure

  $ make
  $ sudo make install
  ```

Comment: it said 'Unable to locate package autotools' in the second step. :(
Then I tried:
'apt-get install -y autotools-dev'
it was installed properly.
But in './autogen.sh'
showed the output like bellow:

Comment: It probably got renamed: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/autotools-dev  Can you confirm this? Ill edit it in if it is correct